Powershell script to show drive health only for drives with a drive letter
I'm made a powershell command that will give me info about physical drive health, in the following format:
DeviceId          : 0
FriendlyName      : WDC WD84PURZ-85B2YY0
OperationalStatus : OK
HealthStatus      : Healthy
Usage             : Auto-Select

... etc. for each drive, filtering out things like thumb drives.
The command I'm using to do this is:
Get-PhysicalDisk | Where-Object { $_.BusType -ne 'USB' } | Select-Object -Property DeviceId, FriendlyName, OperationalStatus, HealthStatus, Usage

I've attempted to make some code that will also filter out drives without a drive letter and to include the drive letter/s associated with the physical disk, e.g.:
DeviceId          : 0
FriendlyName      : WDC WD84PURZ-85B2YY0
OperationalStatus : OK
HealthStatus      : Healthy
Usage             : Auto-Select
Drive/s           : C D

etc.  on the understanding a drive can have multiple partitions and they can have drive letters too.
I'm not too sure how to start.  I tried as below but it emits errors into the output.  I'd like a nice, clean output so I can parse the result into a table elsewhere.  How should I proceed?
Get-PhysicalDisk | Where-Object { $_.BusType -ne 'USB' } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $disk = $_
        try {
            $diskObj = Get-Disk -Number $disk.DeviceId
            $partitions = $diskObj | Get-Partition
            if ($partitions) {
                $partitions | ForEach-Object {
                    $volume = Get-Volume -Partition $_
                    if ($volume.DriveLetter) {
                        [PSCustomObject]@{
                            DeviceId           = $disk.DeviceId
                            FriendlyName       = $disk.FriendlyName
                            OperationalStatus  = $disk.OperationalStatus
                            HealthStatus       = $disk.HealthStatus
                            Usage              = $disk.Usage
                            DriveLetter        = $volume.DriveLetter
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            Write-Warning "Disk with DeviceId $($disk.DeviceId) not found or has no associated partitions."
        }
    }

The kind of errors I get in the output are as below.  Note that 3 of my 5 drives are in a Storage Space and this device id (0) may well be one of them.
Get-Disk : No MSFT_Disk objects found with property 'Number' equal to '0'.  Verify the value of the property and retry.
At C:\users\test\Desktop\health.ps1:5 char:24
+             $diskObj = Get-Disk -Number $disk.DeviceId
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (0:UInt32) [Get-Disk], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound_Number,Get-Disk


What is the output when you run Get-Disk? Is there actually a property called "Number", and is that number ever "0". The error is telling you that is the problem. Do some testing to find out what the correct range of values are for the property Number and then adjust your code accordingly. Also, is $disk.DeviceId a string or object type that can be used by Get-Disk -Number?

Yes there is a property, no there's no number 0.

Maybe it's as simple as you need to add -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue to Get-Disk so it ignores invalid values and continues with the loop.

I actually solved this by inverting the question.  Instead of fetching physical disks and then trying to get drive letters for them, I decided to fetch all drive letters and then find the physical disk they're associated with.  It means physical disk health may be duplicated, i.e. C and D on the same partition will give you two results about the same drive but that's OK.
Get-Volume | Where-Object { $_.DriveLetter -ne $null } | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        $volume = $_ 
        $partitions = Get-Partition | Where-Object { $_.AccessPaths -contains "$($volume.DriveLetter):\" }
        if ($partitions) { 
            $partitions | ForEach-Object { 
                $disk = Get-Disk -Number $_.DiskNumber 
                if ($disk.BusType -ne 'USB') { 
                    [PSCustomObject]@{ 
                        DeviceId = $disk.Number 
                        FriendlyName = $disk.FriendlyName 
                        OperationalStatus = $disk.OperationalStatus 
                        HealthStatus = $disk.HealthStatus 
                        DriveLetter = $volume.DriveLetter 
                    }
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }

